# Найти фразеологизм в тексте

Tags: фразеология, егэ

> И не так уж важно, идёт ли речь о домовых сычах,...

Это из билетов по ЕГЭ. Я должен найти в этом предложении фразеологизм. Я пишу ответ -- *идёт ли речь*. Но правильный ответ в книге -- *идёт речь*. Будет ли это считаться ошибкой на экзамене? Как определить в какой форме писать фразеологизм? Ведь в данном случае можно было бы также написать *речь идёт*.

Comment: @EkaterinaKashtanova4, Вы совершенно напрасно удалили свое сообщение. Я совсем не хотел такой реакции. Давайте обсудим! Пусть будет "фразеологическое единство". http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415951/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8B

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что *ли* здесь применена по ситуации и не относится к устойчивому обороту, названному фразеологизмом с большой натяжкой. Порядок здесь не имеет значения, и слова в нём взаимозаменяемы, что говорит о неправомерности отнесения его к фразеологизмам: *речь* идёт, а может и литься, длиться, выйти, пройти... *Идёт* время, идут года, бои, перемены... Здесь нет никакой трудности перевода, которой характерен «правильный» фразеологизм (*шапка горит*, *повесил нос*). Фразеологизм не составляется каждый раз заново, а воспроизводится в готовом виде. Он замечателен не просто устойчивостью, а неизменяемостью и штучным употреблением, при общей яркой эмоциональной окраске, значения слов (или одного из слов) в его составе

Answer (score -1):

Конечно, частица "ли" не входит состав речевого штампа, которые некоторые лингвисты относят к фразеологизмам.

Comment: Почему вдруг фразеологизм стал "речевым штампом"?

Comment: behemothus, не фразеологизм стал речевым штампом. Некоторые лингвисты речевые штампы относят к фразеологизмам.

Comment: Я не спрашиваю, что там делают "некоторые" лингвисты. Это Вы типичный фразеологизм называете речевым штампом. Или покажите мне лингвиста, который тоже считает эту конструкцию "идет речь" речевым штампом. Я вижу основания отнести его к фразеологизмам, не вижу никаких причин для отречения к "речевым штампам". Могу ошибаться, но готов отстаивать. Вопрос не стоял бы так остро, но вы этим изрядно путаете людей, которым надо к ЕГЭ готовиться, там таких вольностей в терминологии не потерпят.

Comment: *Речевые штампы - это лексически неполноценные слова и выражения, которые иногда справедливо называют "затасканные, избитые выражения". Они мало что добавляют к тому, что хочет сказать оратор, но сильно перегружают его речь.* (Вики).

Comment: behemothus, во-первых, приведите источник, где написано, что это типичный фразеологизм, во-вторых, чем я путаю? Вопрос состоял в том, входит ли частица "ли" в состав (назовем его условно) фразеологизма.  Разве я написал, что входит? Или вы будете утверждать обратное?

Comment: И в-третьих, я обратился на Грамму.ру,чтобы окончательно выяснить, чем является данное выражение. Но в том или ином случае, частица "ли" однозначно не входит в состав данного выражения. Что и хотел узнать автор.

Comment: Ну знаете... Т.е. Вы сначала безапелляционно сказали, а потом "обратились"? А не боитесь что там будет еще более двусмысленная трактовка? И потом, разве с граммой нельзя поспорить? Там столько ляпов.... Я сейчас на "грамоте" спрошу - уверены, что ответ будет такой же? Надо же владеть теорией хоть немного, чтобы не просто следовать советам, а понимать и других учить... Отминусовал с чистой совестью. Насчет "однозначно не входит" у кого будем спрашивать? Попробуйте прочитать то, что я Екатерине написал.

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что вы знаете лучше всех?Де доверяете ни Грамме, ни Грамоте. А кому-нибудь  доверяете?

Comment: Я так не считаю. Почему Вы припысываете мне то, чего я не говорил? Я сказал то, что нехорошо сначала на каких-то "лингвистов", которые что-то там непонятное сказали, а потом бежать искать этих лингвистов на Грамму, где отвечают, кстати, такие же "знатоки", как мы с Вами. А доверюя я академической грамматике, например. Там сказано, что такое фразеологизм. Если я неправильно трактую, объясните в чем. Предлагаю прекратить бесполезную дискуссию. Вопрос исчерпан.