# Фразеологизмы и речевые штампы

Tags: фразеология

Фразеологизмы и речевые штампы.
Вопрос, собственно в том, **как вы понимаете разницу** и почему тот или иной фрагмент текста воспринимается штампом. Подчеркиваю, я не противопоставляю фразеологизм идиоме, тем более - фразеологическому единству. Это вещи на таком уровне сходные. Но штамп - нечто совершенно другое. Возник в связи с сочетанием "речь идет". По мне - очевидный фразеологизм (нечленимое, буквально не переводимое и проч.), никаким образом "штампом" не являющийся.

[Найти фразеологизм в тексте](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415914/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5/)

И второй вопрос. **Если фразеологизм "разрывается" каким-либо словом, разве он перестает быть фразеологизмом?**  *Остаться с [большим] носом*. Тут сомнения такого плана. Утверждается, что порядок слов во фразеологизме не может меняться. А если "с большим носом остаться"? Все это как-то вызывает сомнения в незыблемости фразеологизма как речевой единицы. Хотелось бы комментариев. (Это уже безотносительно к штампу).

Comment: [Примеры из национального корпуса](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EE%F1%F2%E0%F2%FC%F1%FF&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=3&max2=3&lex2=%ED%EE%F1&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=0). Там "гулькин нос" и "нос к носу" затесались, но и "остался с длинным носом" присутствует.

Comment: Да, конечно. Я не сомневался, что что-то такое будет. Интересно, как истолкуют этот факт сторонники незыблемости фразеологизма...

Comment: Думаю тут важно чтобы в фразеологизме присутствовал полный набор слов; порядок может меняться, могут появляться дополнительные характеристики. Но вот заменить "нос" "глазом" не удается - фразеологизм распадается.

Comment: Опять согласен. Но вопрос так не стоит. Добавить слово можно? Переставить? Разорвать словом к фразеологизму не относящемуся? Если три раза нет, то непонятно, чем становятся такие фразы. Если помните, во фразеологизм "идет речь" всего-то добавили частицу "ли". "Идет ли речь". Отнести "ли" к фразеологизму отказались. Значит, либо надо признать, либо, что такая операция ("разбавление" новым словом)  не нарушает целостность фразеологизма в отальном, либо, что фразеологизм перестал им быть. Третьего не дано. Вот я и интересуюсь, что с этим фразеологизмом стало.  Вполне конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Отвечает академик Виноградов :) [Об основных типах фразеологических единиц в русском языке](http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/vinogradov-77d.htm).

Comment: Угу. Спасибо. Вообще-то я, помнится, когда-то читал эту работу, но перечитаю непременно. Но все-таки вряд ли он дает конкретный ответ на мой конкретный сиюминутный вопрос. Про фразеологизм "идет ли речь".

Comment: Возможно здесь "ли" нельзя по-другому поставить. [Зализняк рассказывает об энклитиках](http://elementy.ru/lib/431049?page_design=print): "хороший русский язык до сих пор требует такой фразы: "Иван же Петрович не согласен". Энклитика внедряется внутрь даже такой крепкой единицы, как Иван Петрович". Т.е. "ли" не является частью фразеологизма, ее можно поставить только на вторую позицию после "ритмико-синтаксического барьера". Т.е. здесь фразеологизм "идет речь" и законным образом внедрившаяся между словами частица "ли", не являющаяся частью фразеологизма.

Comment: ну что сказать... Умница Зализник. Давайте подытожим. **Как минимум в одном случае посторонняя вещь (энклитическая частица) может забраться внутрь фразеологизма, при этом фразеологизм не перестаёт быть фразеологизмом и не переходит в разряд, например, речевых штампов.**  Японимаю, что фразеологизм и речевой штамп - это понятия их разных областей (первое - семантичекое, второе скорее стилистическое), но так уж разговор пошел у меня в другой теме. В целом я весьма удовлетворен.

Comment: Про энклитики говорил Зализняк.

Comment: Да, конечно. Я не авторов спутал, а фамилии... ))) При Виноградове теория частиц вообще была в зачаточном состоянии, это результат последних тридцати, максимум - сорока лет. Я в школе учился - про частицы вообще избегали говорить вслух.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже и забыл про этот вопрос, а ответа так и нет... Закрыть не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Порядок слов в фразеологизмах может меняться. Толочь воду в ступе - в ступе воду толочь; манна небесная - небесная манна. Слова также могут меняться, добавляться или исчезать. Упаси Бог - упаси Царица Небесная - сохрани Господь. Утереть нос - утереть нос Ване - утереть нос сестре.

Comment: Порядок слов можно менять, менять слова и новые разные вместо них вставлять. Не вопрос. Только что получим-то, утрём нос фразеологизму?